# React Leaflet: Get objects from MongoDB to Leaflet map as markers (using node.js and express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB (using node.js and express) and show them as markers on a Leaflet map, using react leaflet. However, I always get an error: **Unhandled rejection (TypeError): this.state.images.map is not a function**. I am not sure why I get this error, since my data looks fine in the console log.

My server:

```
imageRouter.get((req, res, next) => {
    ImageEntry.find({})
        .then(images => {
            res.status(200).json({
                images,
            });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
});
```

My client (API.js):

```
    export async function getImages() {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    return response.json();  
}
```

My client (App.js):

```
        state = {
         location: {
          lat: 63.430515,
          lng: 10.395053,
        },
        zoom: 5,
        images: [],
      }

componentDidMount() {
    getImages()
      .then(images => {
        this.setState({
          images
        });
      });
  }

render(){
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng];

    console.log(this.state.images);

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a 
            href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
            contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {
            this.state.images.map(image => (
              <Marker
                key={image._id}
                position={[image.latitude, image.longitude]}
                icon={imageIcon}>
                <Popup>
                  <p><em>{image.prosjekt}</em> {image.prosjektOmrade}</p>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            ))}
        </Map>
    );
  }
```

I have tried to print images inside the render to see if I get the right result. When I refresh the page, the array is empty but after som ms the array have some objects inside. It is showing the following:

```
[]
 length: 0
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

After som ms

```
{images: Array(4)}
    images: Array(4)
     0: {_id: "6026b6c272d2e50d47533055", prosjekt: "E6KAA", prosjektOmrade: "Holvegen", parsell: 1200, kategori: "VVS", …}
     1: {_id: "602804da7be224141e19b38d", prosjekt: "E6KAA", prosjektOmrade: "Holvegen", parsell: 1200, kategori: "VVS", …}
     2: {_id: "602ab78bbde3a7233bf9954e", prosjekt: "E6KAA", prosjektOmrade: "Bro", parsell: 233, kategori: "Bro", …}
     3: {_id: "602d31a9311aec0f1bef820f", prosjekt: "E6KAA", prosjektOmrade: "rundkjøring", parsell: 400, kategori: "Vei", …}
     length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

I can't figure out why I get the error, really hope anyone can help me.
Really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably `this.state.images` is empty for a few seconds before data is fetched. try using an expression `this.state.images.length > 0 && this.state.images.map...` to ensure data array is populated

Comment: It helps against the error message, but no markers are made on the map... Do you know of a way to make the function wait to run until the values ​​have arrived in the array? @kboul

Comment: Are you sure the response is an array of objects and not an array of array of objects for instance or sth else?

Comment: That is a good question. I thought it was just an array, but when you mention it maybe it is an array of array of objects. When I see it in the console I have to "open" the **{images: Array(4)}** and then "open" **images: Array(4)**, to be able to see all the objects. Do you know how to get to det innermost array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidMount() {
    getImages()
      .then(images => {
        this.setState({
          images: images.images
        });
      });
  }
```

or by destructuring

```
 componentDidMount() {
        getImages()
          .then(({images}) => {
            this.setState({ images });
          });
      }
```

From the comments:

1. `this.state.images` is empty for a few seconds before data is fetched. try using an expression `this.state.images.length > 0 && this.state.images.map`... to ensure data array is populated
2. If the model of data returned is an array of arrays of objects just access the data by making `images.images` but it is difficult to say exactly without knowing the exact form of the data returned.